# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while ordering by date or string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting a conversion error when ordering in a complex query. I've distilled it down to the following:

```
DECLARE @sortBy VARCHAR(25) = 'Route'
DECLARE @sortDirection VARCHAR(25) = 'DESC'

select * from dbo.headers
order by case when @sortDirection = 'DESC' then
    case
        when @sortBy = 'Route' then route
        when @sortBy = 'DateCompleted' then dateCompleted
    end
end desc
```

Oddly works fine if I change the `sortBy` variable to 'DateCompleted'.

Would appreciate some input here as I've been trying to figure it out for a few hours at least.

I've tried sorting by the date column itself, which works fine. But I want to order by other things too, resulting in a conversion error. The dateCompleted column is a nullable datetime.

Comment: Split the values. `ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'Route' THEN route END, CASE WHEN @sortBy = 'DateCompleted' then dateCompleted end` etc. Side note: sorting by `CASE` is really inefficient. You would be better off using dynamic SQL

Comment: Or using an IF block to execute *different* queries. You aren't ordering by different fields, you're ordering by the result of the `CASE` expression whose type is determined by the [data type precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Date types have a higher precedence so the expression must return a date. If the field *doesn't* contain a date you'll get a conversion error

Comment: Thanks. Yeah we're going to look at building up the query dynamically. This is a step towards moving the paging off the API and onto the database (MVP was very much an MVP..)

Comment: `I want to order by other things too` not like this. That's not how SQL, the language, works. This `CASE` will result in errors in most databases, not just SQL Server

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos that seems like the root cause of the issue.

Comment: You can't just hack the database. It's not an implementation detail. If your API language has an ORM like EF Core, the *easy* way is to use the ORM's Order, Take or Skip calls. That will generate the appropriate SQL. If you have a lot of data that needs to be chunked though, every successive call will take longer. In that case it's a *lot* cheaper to retrieve the list of IDs, chunk them then return the rows matching those IDs

Comment: For these kind of sorting queries, i would recommend doing it with dynamic sql, it's easier to get it right and the optimizer might thank you. Alternatively, it's better to sort each field separately something like: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN  sortBy = 'Route' then route END, CASE when @sortBy = 'DateCompleted' then dateCompleted end, ...` The unsorted values become NULL, and there's no conversion happening here

Answer (score -1):

It might be because it is trying to convert a "route" to a DATE or DATETIME or whatever the datatype for "dateCompleted" is.

You could try CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), dateCompleted, 121)

Comment: That does work. How strange though that it's necessary, especially when sorting by ascending works fine. There must be more to it..

Comment: Scratch that, ascending doesn't work either without this change. I'll update my question.